# ProGuard fails in building an app with Android SDK Platform 33

Tags: android

I observed the following error in building an Android app with Android SDK Platform 33.

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
> ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

Because I found the following trace in the build log, I tried to use 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.1.1' to fix the issue.

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read
> [/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-33/optional/android.car.jar]
> (Can't process class
> [android/car/Car$CarServiceLifecycleListener.class] (Unsupported
> version number [55.0] (maximum 54.0, Java 10)))

After that, I faced another issue that occurred in the task "transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebugAndroidTest."

When multiDexEnabled turned off, the task right above was successful.

Should I use the upgraded ProGuard and turn off multiDexEnabled for development with SDK 33?
I don't think that it is a standard way.
If anyone knows about the same issue, could you please give advice?

Pre-requisite:

- minSdkVersion: 19
- targetSdkVersion: 33
- compileSdkVersion: 33
- buildToolsVersion: 28.0.3
- gradle: 4.6
- language: Java
- JDK: 1.7

Thank you.

Comment: latest version of proguard? what happens when you enable java8?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Shark.  
I checked the class version of the library called android.car.jar located at "Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33\optional."  
The class version is 55, meaning it is compiled with Java 11.  
I believe the default ProGuard used in the Android build system doesn't support class version 55.  
So I added the below in my Gradle file.  
  configurations.all {  
      resolutionStrategy {  
          force 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.1.1'  
      }  
  }

This solution would be a workaround.  
I am looking for a more suitable way.

Comment: have you tried bumping your gradle to something newer, e.g. 7? like, you're targetting latest, but your environment is years old. Time to pay off some of that tech debt and upgrade things a bit.

Comment: Your device seems to be the only way to solve the issue.
I am going to struggle with the incompatibility issues in upgrading building tools.
However, I think there is no other way.
Thank you for your advice again, @Shark
Once I successfully fix it, I will share the outcome.